# shiny htmlOutput() – export to pdf

Tags: html, pdf, download, shiny, r-markdown

I want to export html objects from shiny app to pdf. In order to export table, I was using .Rmd template (based on [How to make pdf download in shiny app response to user inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018983/how-to-make-pdf-download-in-shiny-app-response-to-user-inputs)), however I do not know how to pass html object to PDF in shiny app.

Example app:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width=4,
      htmlOutput("Table1"),
      htmlOutput("Table2"),
      htmlOutput("Table3")
    ))
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){


  #****************************************
  #* Output Components

  output$Table1 <- renderUI({
    HTML("<div class='progress-group'>
                    <span class='progress-text'>Add Products to Cart</span>
                    <span class='progress-number'><b>160</b>/200</span>
                    <div class='progress sm'>
                      <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-aqua' style='width: 80%'></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>")
  })

  output$Table2 <- renderUI({
    HTML("<div class='progress-group'>
                    <span class='progress-text'>Complete Purchase</span>
         <span class='progress-number'><b>310</b>/400</span>
         <div class='progress sm'>
         <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-red' style='width: 100%'></div>
         </div>
         </div>")
  })

  output$Table3 <- renderUI({
    HTML("<div class='progress-group'>
                    <span class='progress-text'>Visit Premium Page</span>
         <span class='progress-number'><b>480</b>/800</span>
         <div class='progress sm'>
         <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-green' style='width: 10%'></div>
         </div>
         </div>")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Did you already solve this?