# Export Shiny page to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, highcharts, shiny

I'm trying to export a page from my Shiny dashboard to PDF. I am able to generate an HTML export (following [this Shiny manual](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/rmarkdown.html) and [this one](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html)), but with PDF I constantly run into the problem of not being able to include my `Highcharts` graphs, since they're HTML. I'm not including any code because I think the problem is more fundamental: is there even a possibility to include Highchart graphs in a PDF export?

I know there's a `Highcharter` export module (`hc_exporting()`) that allows individual graphs to be saved as PDF, but not an entire page. Simply using "Print page" within a browser cuts off most graphs because they don't fit on the page.

Is the answer here really "no"? What do other people do to allow Shiny users to export dashboard pages to PDF?

NB. I know there are similar questions out there, but none of them solve my particular issue:

- [Solution when using `ggplot`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40273260/1092247),  but doesn't work for `Highcharts`
- [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39772774/1092247), >3 years old, which never got an answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this, but I have not tried:

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#printPdf').click(function () {
    domtoimage.toPng(document.body)
      .then(function (blob) {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('body').width(), $('body').height()]);
        pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('body').width(), $('body').height());
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
      });
  });
});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"),
    tags$script(js)
  ),
  br(),
  actionButton("printPdf", "Export page to PDF"),
  ......
)
```

Comment: Great idea Stéphane, merci beaucoup, but unfortunately it only saves the top part of the page? Not really sure I understand the solution enough to be able to adapt it?

Comment: @rvrvrv Maybe the dimensions are too large to fit in one page? I don't know. Could you try to replace `$('body').width()` with `$('body').width()/2` and `$('body').height()` with `$('body').height()/2`. What does it give?