# Export R Shiny Page to PDF

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I have a large Shiny application that has a number of prompts, then generates tables and plot based on those inputs. I don't use rmarkdown or knitr or anything to format the output. I just use the standard Shiny elements (`sidebarPanel`, `mainPanel`, etc.). For the plots and tables I use the standard reactive `renderPlot` and `renderTable` objects.
I'm looking for an easy way to have a button called "Export to PDF" that exports the elements on the page to a PDF document.

I've looked into using knitr and rmarkdown to generate a document with some fancy formatting (see [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html) and [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html) for examples).
The problem is that it appears that I'll need to regenerate the tables and plots either within the Rmd file or the server.R within a `downloadHandler` object, and I'd like to avoid that.

Is there any way to output the page as a pdf more easily. More specifically, is there any way to directly reference the output tables and plots (i.e. the `output$` objects) from within the Rmd file so that plots and tables don't need to be generated twice.

Edit: Here is some simplified code. Note `getDataset()` is a reactive function that queries a database based on the inputs.
My goal is to simply add an "Export" button that exports the already-generated plots and table. (Also as a side note, is there any way I can get a reactive dataset that is shared among all reactive elements? i.e. not need to have `ds <- getDataset()` in every object?)

Server

```
output$hist <- renderPlot({
  ds <- getDataset()
  # do data transformations
    
  ggplot(ds, aes(val)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = binSize, aes(fill = ..count..)) +
    labs(title = "val dist", x = "val", y = "Count") + 
    scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "green", high = "red", guide = FALSE) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(min(ds$val), quantile(ds$val, 0.99))) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=maxY, linetype=3)
})

output$time <- renderPlot({
  ds <- getDataset()
  # do data transformations
  ggplot(ds, aes(as.POSIXlt(unixTime, origin="1970-01-01", tz="UTC"), val), colour = val) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(ds$val), quantile(ds$val, 0.99))) +
    labs(title = "Val Over Time", x = "Time (UTC)", y = "val (ms)") +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.3, size = 0.7) +
    geom_smooth()
})
output$stats <- renderTable({
  statsDf = getDataset()
  # do data transformations
  statsDf
})
```

UI

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Results"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateInput("startDateTime", "Start Date:", value = "2016-10-21"),
      textInput("startTime", "Start Time", "00:00:00"),
      br(),
      dateInput("endDateTime", "End Date:", value = "2016-10-21"),
      textInput("endTime", "End Time", value = "02:00:00"),
      br(),
      submitButton("Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Plots",
                           plotOutput("hist"),
                           plotOutput("time"),
                  tabPanel("Statistics", tableOutput("stats"))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: I'm using ggplot. I'll edit the post and put in some sample code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all , you should really produce a reproducible example not just a sample of your code. We should copy and paste your code and it will run.

#### The idea

1. Since you are using `ggplot2` which is king of `grid` plots, I think one easy option to save plots/tables is to use `gridExtra` package. Using `grid.arrange` or `arrangeGrobs` you can save your grobs to predefined device. Then, downloadhandler will do the download.
2. To not regenerate all the plots each time, I think one solution is to save them in a global variable that you update each time you change the plot. Here `reactiveValues` come in rescue to store plots and tables ad dynamic variable.

### Solution

#### ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Save ggplot plot/table without regenration"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton('export')
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("p1"),
      plotOutput("p2"),
      tableOutput("t1")
    )
  )
))
```

#### server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  ## vals will contain all plot and table grobs
  vals <- reactiveValues(p1=NULL,p2=NULL,t1=NULL)

  ## Note that we store the plot grob before returning it 
  output$p1 <- renderPlot({
    vals$p1 <- qplot(speed, dist, data = cars)
    vals$p1
  })

  output$p2 <- renderPlot({
    vals$p2 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl)
    vals$p2
  })
  ## same thing for th etable grob
  output$t1 <- renderTable({
    dx <- head(mtcars)
    vals$t1 <- tableGrob(dx)
    dx
  })
  ## clicking on the export button will generate a pdf file 
  ## containing all grobs
  output$export = downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"plots.pdf"},
    content = function(file) {
     pdf(file, onefile = TRUE)
     grid.arrange(vals$p1,vals$p2,vals$t1) 
     dev.off()
    }
  )
})
```

Comment: Ah, very clever. So I take it that there is no way to use r markdown without needing to regenerate the plots? That's unfortunate, but your idea is perfect for a quick fix!

Apologies for not including actual code. I'm sure that I'd be violating a number of NDAs by posting the full code to a public website. I was just looking for a general strategy anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @agstudy: I am using `plotly` plots and `datatable` for the tables. I am unable to use something similar to this for those elements. I get an error `"Error in gList: only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`. Is there a way I can convert `plotly` and `datatable` elements to `grobs`?

Comment: @krish sorry I don't know. I don't use plotly.

Comment: @krish Did you ever get this working with plotly and DT?

Comment: @DanteSmith How about you?

Comment: @Bat Masterson was asking about also exporting tables to pdf, so this answer does not provide solution for the problem as a whole :( I would also appreciate the answer for the question.

Comment: @BatMasterson see the answer to this Q for how to use a parameterized rmd to output a formatted report without re-running your whole process https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018983/how-to-make-pdf-download-in-shiny-app-response-to-user-inputs